# IE10 how to enable download file dialoug box like in IE8

Tags: windows, download, internet-explorer-10

In older versions of IE when downloading a file you were presented a nice dialog box (I don't have enough reputations to post images) where you were then asked where you want to download to. I'm now doing some work on a machine that has IE 10 and I get the yellowish box at the very bottom of the screen instead.

As I'm doing work that involves using automation to download these files, this causes several problems:
1 - This new box is not actually a 'window' so I cannot programmatically recognize if the window is active
2 - You cannot use keystrokes to 'tab' to the buttons

Bottom line, is there any way to get the old style download window in IE10? I cannot use any other browser. Thanks

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not a feature that is possible in newer versions of Internet Explorer. Although on that box, you can click view all downloads, which will pop up another window you can tab to and will host all downloads until you close it.